# Can already opened event logs of PowerShell's event properties screens on Windows be hacked by hackers in milliseconds?

Tags: windows, attack-prevention, logging, powershell

I am wondering some issues about event log safety of powershell. I think is it possible to alter the powershell itself. But theorically the event log should show us every attempt made in powershell such as opening commands or codes that makes powershell work. My question is can already opened event logs of PowerShell's event properties screens on windows operating system be hacked offline by hackers if I check them regularly and see no change does it mean they are safe or can be changed by hackers even in millisecconds?

If I check them regularly and see no change does it mean they are safe or can be changed by hackers in a briefly short time?

I need clear answers and i need to understand the possibilities
as far as i know event log is not an online system so they can attack offline, i tried to mention can they play with event id codes regularly on an offline system. My concern is safety of event id history of powershell's event logs.

Comment: If I can access the properties without using Powershell, then of course.